# Excel: Count the number of occurrences

Tags: excel, sorting

I have data in the following format

[image: data]

(about 2000 lines)

What is an efficient way to count the number of wins and loses for each coefficient?

I have tried to split each coefficient into separate column and then sort my wins and loses, but this is very time consuming.

I want to get this table:

[image: table2]

Thank you

Comment: Please explain/show what you want the result to look like.

Comment: Something like this http://joxi.ru/yPAFVP3JTJACNa5RcKk

Comment: [pivot table](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-HA102840046.aspx) or [countifs](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countifs-function-HA010047494.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make it into a pivot table and then have it show subtotals for each change in the K column. You may need to use the C column to insert a 1 in each cell to give it a value to add.

Comment: no need to insert anything in Column C. just put the status in both the x axis of the pivot table and in the data section as a count.

Answer (score 2):

As others suggest, using a `Pivot Table` will get these results. Here's a graphical to help:

- Select the range
- In the Ribbon, `Insert -> Pivot Table`

[image]

- In the Pivot table window, check the box next to both columns in the `Fields` area, move `K` column to the Rows list and `Status` to the Columns list.

[image]